# Export R table to include curly brackets

Tags: r, matrix, export

I have a matrix in R and need to use it as input in another software where the rows need to be wrapped in curly brackets, e.g.

```
{{0,2,-2,0},{-1,1,1,1}}
```

One way is to extract each row separately and then concatenate curly brackets but I'm wondering whether there is a more intelligent way to do this. Thank you!

```
m <- matrix(c(0,2,-2,0,-1,1,1,1), 2, byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: This format looks a lot like json. Maybe the json_lite package may help you.

Comment: another option: `sprintf('{%s}', toString(sprintf('{%s}', apply(m, 1, toString))))`

Comment: @rawr Thank you for editing and the suggestion. It works!